# How can I re-render screen after call an request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I Have two screens, First Screen I get all playlist on it "Playlists" and when I click to any of them I navigate to the second screen "playlist details" that are contained all songs on this playlist "it was passed from the first Screen".

So in the playlist details screen, I have a list of songs when and i make a function to delete this song "send a request to API".

So my question is how can i re-render the playlist details screen after I delete one song in it?

Playlist details screen

```
class PlaylistDetails extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...
      playListSongs: props.navigation.state.params.playListSongs,
      All_tunes: [],
      ...
    };
  }


 // Remove song from a specific playlist
  removeSongFromPlaylist = async (track_id, playListID) => {
    try {
      const {token} = this.state;
      let AuthStr = `Bearer ${token}`;
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: AuthStr,
      };
      let response = await API.post(
        '/my_play_list_track_delete',
        {tracks_id: track_id, myplaylist_id: playListID},
        {headers},
      );
      let message = response.data.data;
      alert(message);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };



render(){

....
  <FlatList
      data={this.state.playListSongs}
      keyExtractor={(song, index) => song.id.toString()}
      removeClippedSubviews={false}
      contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
      extraData={this.state}
      renderItem={this._renderSongs}
  />
...
}
}
```

**Solve It ‍♂️**

I just solve it after submitting my question  So I update the state after removing a song from the playlist, "*Anyway Thanks For mosmk and brycelikesdogs*"

```
removeSongFromPlaylist = async (track_id, playListID) => {
...

 this.setState({
        playListSongs: this.state.playListSongs.filter(
          item => item.track.id !== track_id,
        ),
      });
...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your screen will rerender if it's props or state changes. When you remove a song from the playlist, you should either also update your state by either deleting it from the state as well or by refetching the api data.

```
// Remove song from a specific playlist
  removeSongFromPlaylist = async (track_id, playListID) => {
    try {
      const {token} = this.state;
      let AuthStr = `Bearer ${token}`;
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: AuthStr,
      };
      let response = await API.post(
        '/my_play_list_track_delete',
        {tracks_id: track_id, myplaylist_id: playListID},
        {headers},
      );
      let message = response.data.data;
      // update your state here to remove the track
      alert(message);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways:

1- The first is to update the state of list of songs (called optimistic updates) without actually waiting for the API request to be done which is better for user experience (no loading indicators).

2- The second is to re-fetch the songs after awaiting the API call for deleting the song.